How to cover up a kitchen pass-through window without permanent changes?
My home has a large kitchen pass-through window with a wooden frame that opens into a room that I use as my office. I want to isolate my office room from the kitchen by closing off / covering up the pass-through window for visual separation, and preferably decent sound-separation too. How can I do this? What solutions/materials do you suggest?
However, this is a rental home. I cannot make big permanent changes since this is a rental home; I could drill a few holes for screws & nails. The size of the opening is roughly 95" x 38"; the depth at the top is 6". Budget: upto a few hundred dollars is fine.
I thought of using some kind of panels (like plywood, or foam or soundproofing panels), but I don't know how to affix it to the frame.


Don't overlook checking with the owner first, just in case they might agree to let you pay for some or all changes you really want in exchange for what they might perceive to be an improvement to their property.

Update: Now that I see your opening size, and the way the counter top creates the bottom sill, I favor Huesmann's answer. It's simpler in this situation and will look nicer.
An alternative to relying on friction fit would be to use double-sided removable foam tape and set upper and lower plates of 2x2 or 2x3, then fit studs snugly at each end and the center to add some compression. These wouldn't even need to be fastened--it won't move once the panels are installed. Fill with 1½" or 2" foam panel and cover it as described in that answer.
Before you begin installing parts, set your panel material in place and trace the opening. Cut ~1/8" smaller than that for easier fitment (assuming you plan to wrap the opening with molding). Cut from the back side to reduce tearout.

Sandwich it.

Since the opening is so wide, I suggest laying a faux bottom plate across the counter top to support the panels. Cut a piece of board to a comfortable length and use two strips of removable double-sided foam tape to secure it. This board should be the same width as the dimension from outer face to outer face of casing (or use two boards, each flush with a casing face and with cross-blocking screwed to the tops to keep them parallel).

Cut two facing panels of your choice of plywood, fiberboard, or whatever. These should be oversized to cover the casing in a way that looks decent, and they should be fairly rigid (self-supporting*). Maybe just larger than the outer casing dimensions would create a clean look.

To one panel, attach one or more foam panels that just fit inside the actual opening, to deaden sound. Use panel adhesive, double-sided tape, etc.

Ring the casing with removeable double-sided foam tape.

Press the panels in place. Depending on what panel material you chose, this may be all that's needed. If it feels solid (check after a couple days), all good.

If not, drill through both panels just inside the original opening at a few points and squeeze the assembly with long bolts and barrel nuts ("sex bolts") or similar. With just a bit of tension there should be plenty of friction to keep things in place, especially if you fitted the foam bits well to the opening.


Now, if you want to restore the original cased appearance, install new casing over your panels. This could also be mounted with panel adhesive or foam tape.
If you want to get really fancy-pants, fit 1/4" plywood inside the existing casing, just lapping onto the frame (about 1/4"). This takes a lot of precision, of course, but might give the cleanest look. See my note below about thin panels.

* If you want to use thinner panel material, bond rigid 2" foam to both panels to add stiffness, fitting inside the original opening.

I considered the foam tape in my answer, but given my experience using it for a similar task (storm windows), it was difficult to remove in its entirety—it left some of the adhesive and foam behind.

A good quality removable in a stable temperature environment should still be removable after several years.

Could get a 4x8 pink foam board, cut it just a little larger than the opening so it's a press fit, and press it in there.  Then get a couple sheets of cheap 1/4" ply or lauan, cut those to fit the opening and glue them onto the foam board.  (Could be stained/painted before gluing.)  Then run some quarter round (or other preferred molding) around the edge of each sheet of plywood and glue or finish nail it to the plywood.
This way, the original opening is basically left untouched.  When you need to move out, you can just knock your temporary wall out and toss it.  Or leave it for the next inhabitant—they may want something similar.

Now that I've seen how large the opening is and the bottom situation I like this answer better than mine. It would be simpler and look cleaner.

This is cheap and easy but note that this will do very little for acoustic isolation. If OP wanted some sound deadening, they could frame it out a bit thicker and put some rockwool in between the foam and the outer plywood on one side.

@DeusXMachina it's not clear how much acoustic isolation is required—what other noise is there?  If it needs to be very isolated, OP could get two foam boards and sandwich your Rockwool between them.  (I think it'll be easier to adhere 1/4" ply to foam board than it will to Rockwool.)  There appears to be plenty of wall thickness for some additional foam and Rockwool.  OP could just start with one foam board and add ply to only one side, then determine later if the amount of noise reduction is sufficient. If so, just add the other ply. If not, then add the Rockwool, etc.

It'll do at least as much sound isolation as the door hanging right next to it. Much more effort brings quickly diminishing returns.
